# Скрепить спрайты внутри node Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, xcode, анимация, swift, spritekit

Как "привязать" один спрайт к другому внутри нода?
У меня есть персонаж, во время движения воспроизводится анимация( персонаж наклоняется в сторону движение). Движение происходит за счет акселерометра.
 У персонажа есть шапка. Шапки будут меняться (менять цвет), поэтому было принято решение делать ее отдельным спрайтом. Мне нужно что бы шапка наклонялась вместе с персонажем во время движения.
Пытался двигать ее отдельно во время движения, но получается немного запоздало, да и выглядит это как будто шапка живет отдельной жизнью. Можно ли как-то "привязать" шапку к голове? что бы она двигалась вместе с персонажем. Буду рад любым советам. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `SKPhysicsJoint` можно скрепить 2 физических тела. 
Вот тут подобный вопрос:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579586/how-can-i-pin-sprites-to-other-sprites-in-sprite-kit